# Is there any way to get vector pathData prorgamatically and draw shape using that pathData in canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, vector-graphics

i have world map xml  file  which i imported in android studio.and want to get path data of countries dyanmically.
How can i achieve this.After getting the pathData i want to plot that points in canvas.Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: @pskink i have edited it .check it.

Comment: please share your file

Answer (score 2):

If your image is an SVG imported as an XML file, and want to access the path, rather than use the `drawable` to set an image, you can simply save the path as a `string` resource.

One library that I know of that allows plotting using pathData is [AnimatedSvgView](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView). You should be able to find similar libraries if you search online.

If that's not exactly what you need, then you can use their code as a reference and implement a custom Canvas and graphics behaviour in your app.